# Possible bug in OpenCV2.4 capturing frames from video

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

Could it be that there is a bug in **OpenCV2.4 highgui** for capturing frames from video in windows?

I installed both the precompiled libraries, the ones compiled by me, I can compile everything perfectly and I can run my programs if

they are image based. The problem is only for **videos**. OpenCV crashes in this function always:

```
 virtual IplImage* retrieveFrame(int)
    {
        unsigned char* data = 0;
        int step=0, width=0, height=0, cn=0;

        if(!ffmpegCapture ||
           !icvRetrieveFrame_FFMPEG_p(ffmpegCapture,&data,&step,&width,&height,&cn)) <-------CRASHES HERE
           return 0;
        cvInitImageHeader(&frame, cvSize(width, height), 8, cn);
        cvSetData(&frame, data, step);
        return &frame;
    }
```

This is inside the class **cap_ffmpeg.cpp** and is called by **VideoCapture**.

I tried versions 2.4.2 and 2.4.9. My programes were working finde with opencv2

---

**More information**

- Windows 7
- Build the projects with cmake (important as it could be that cmake is not building/finding the right codecs)
- VisualStudio 9 2008
- OpenCV 2.4.2

**EDIT**

It looks like it is actually a [bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2115), so, how can I solve this problem and change my code to be able to read avi files?

Comment: Why not? It is software :) Looks like your problem described http://code.opencv.org/issues/2115

Comment: @Sergey hehe, yes I believe it, but it is a pain. I need to develope and now I have to fight with this... patience

Comment: as per description you need to downgrade 2.4->2.1 or just fix it by yourself and publish your patch to help other people :) Per my knowledge it is bad idea to use ffmpeg on Windows. AFAIR it should be DirectDraw capture for OpenCV, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a temporary solution I decided to re-encode the videos so OpenCV doesn't use the ffmpeg. I used **VirtualDub** with the **microsoft video 1** compression, which uses "msvidc32.dll" driver.

It works with all my videos so it is enough by now as I can keep working with OpenCV in windows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I downloaded VirtualDub, but it did not open one of my avi video because of its FMP4 encode. So in the end, the solution that solved the problem was to install ffdshow, a decoder for windows. See this link: http://www.moviecodec.com/video-codecs/fmp4-codec-with-virtualdub-45814/

Then I do not need to use VirtualDub anymore to re-encode my video anymore!

Answer (score 1):

if your using x64. Please use opencv_ffmpeg245_64.dll this solves may solve the problem. Or rename opencv_ffmpeg245_64.dll to opencv_ffmpeg245.dll may solve the problem.